# Cryptographic Algorithm

Tags: algorithm-design

I'd like to find out the cryptographic algorithm which uses only lowercase letters and numbers to encrypt a message, and it has 256 bits (always).
For example:

> fff51ebcad2c44c75d7d5d4c5184b3e4

Comment: Who says it is even a cryptographic algorithm? It could be simply random hexadecimal values. That said, my guess is something like a hex output of SHA-256.

Comment: Only lowercase letters and numbers is simply [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) encoding, which has nothing inherently to do with crypto.

Comment: Ohhh you may be right!

Comment: Could it be AES-128?       ÿõ¼­,DÇ]}]LQ„³ä